# How to remove /** */ (slash and star) in my script?

Tags: php

In my scripts have so much /**  */ (slash and star) in muiltiline as the below picture
[image: my script]

I use this code to remove it.

```
$addFile = "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myscript\\myfile.php";
$getData = file_get_contents($addFile);
$content = array("/** \n*/","/**  \n*/"); //1 whitespace and 2 whitespaces
$replaceData = str_replace($content,"",$getData);
$addData = file_put_contents($address,$afterData);
print_r($addData);
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it's a single file, why not manually remove it? Or keep the comments, they usually contain useful information to the admin/developer using the script.

Comment: Forgot a space. Consider a regex and match any amount of whitespace with `\s*`.

Comment: `preg_replace('~/\*\*.*?\*/~s', '', $str);` ?

Comment: It is not a single file. Many files! :)